# Python program failing with input greater than 3 digits

Tags: python

I'm doing [Project Euler's problem 35](http://projecteuler.net/problem=35) and my code is failing with a max value of over 999, but works fine before that.

The "count" stops at 22, not calculating any prime numbers over 999.

```
import itertools
import time

def isPrime(n):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return n == 2
    d = 3
    while d * d <= n:
        if n % d == 0:
            return False
        d += 2
    return True

t=time.time()
count=0
Range=1000000
for a in range(2,Range):   
    if isPrime(a):
        alist=[]
        perms=[]
        for n in str(a):
            alist.append(n)
        for n in itertools.permutations(alist):
            num=int("".join(n))
            perms.append(num)
        if all(isPrime(l) for l in perms):
            count+=1

print("there are ", count, " circular primes")
print("time=",time.time()-t,"s")
```

Can anyone work out why this is happening?

Comment: Define "failing"? Is it throwing an exception, incorrectly calculating?

Comment: Well, have you tried outputing the list of the primes as well? How do you know 22 is wrong? etc...

Comment: yeah, I tried all that, the wiki of circular primes give plenty of values above that.

Comment: You might be low on RAM, try switching from `range()` to `xrange()` since the latter hogs less space. Also check out the other answers below for better solutions to the problem using `itertools`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first four digit cyclic prime is (I think) 1193. The simplest way to troubleshoot is just to look at what happens with that number. The problem is that `itertools.permutations` generates *all* permutations, not cyclic rotations. The cyclic rotations of 1193 are

```
[1193, 3119, 9311, 1931]
```

Your code is generating a much bigger list:

```
[1931, 1913, 1391, 1319, 1193, 1139, 9131, 9113, 9311, 9311, 9113, 9131, 3191, 3119, 3911, 3911, 3119, 3191, 1193, 1139, 1913, 1931, 1319, 1391]
```

1391, for instance, isn't prime.

Comment: Ahhhh that's it, I figured it was a silly mistake like that, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You're not reading the problem. You only want rotations, not all permutations.

This will generate the rotations to test:

```
a_str = str(a)
perms = [ int(a_str[i:] + a_str[0:i]) for i in range(1,len(a_str)) ]
```